# How to copy a table to another with primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy

I am using this query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO table1 
FROM table2
```

To copy a table; it doesn't copy the primary key from `table2` to `table1` as Primary key. It just copies all columns - not constraints.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? With Postgres you can use `create table .. like...`

Comment: ...and with sql server you can use ssis or simply script table as create...

Comment: If its oracle use `impdp` and `expdp` with `remap_table`..for quick n best results.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 visual studio 2010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Create New Table with All Constraints and Index in Sql Server 2008 R2?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/65734/60970) ;).

Comment: i want to do this at runtime this shows process manually

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge In SQL server it's not possible your requirement but in case you need same structure with primary key first generate script for existing table then create new table.

using ssms->object explorer->expand databases->select database->right click on table and generate script